# Facebook error crash in FetchedAppGateKeepersManager in Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin, crashlytics

Couple a days a go, we uploaded a new version to market. Few days later some crashes pop up in crashlytics...

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.facebook.internal.C$a.a()' on a null object reference
_____________________
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.facebook.internal.C$a.a()' on a null object reference
       at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppGateKeepersManager$2.run + 154(FetchedAppGateKeepersManager.java:154)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 873(Handler.java:873)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 99(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 214(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 7073(ActivityThread.java:7073)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 493(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 964(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

After see that error we went to bitbucket to see if someone changed some line related with facebook login, etc.. But all the code is still the same from versions before..

I'm not able to understand what is going on, or the reason of this crash.

Some knows what is about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They discovered the issue and fixed it in this commit: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/commit/ac567905e7c29aca5a4e0c0aa10e9412b2b4748f

Another classic episode of the Facebook SDK, which brought me a ton of ANR last week in version 5.4.0. I recommend you downgrade to version 4.40.0 and wait.

Edit:
They fixed and released a bump version. Update sdk to version 5.5.1 to resolve the issue.